# How to mock go-plugin funcs in golang?

Tags: go, go-testing, gomock

```
# I want to mock this function
func testCheckPluginFile(fName string){
    plugin, _ := plugin.Open(path.Join("/I/expect/folder/","/plugin-lib-test/"+fName))
    plugin.Lookup("symbol")
}
```

```
# So I put this func like this
func testCheckPluginFile(fName string,pluginOpen func (path string) (*plugin.Plugin, error)){
    plugin, _ := pluginOpen(path.Join("/I/expect/folder/","/plugin-lib-test/"+fName))
    plugin.Lookup("symbol")
}
```

But I can't do it beacuse of  the `plugin.Plugin.lookup`

Do u have another way to solve it ?

Answer (score 0):

> How to mock [...]plugin funcs in go[...]?

You cannot.

If you want to test that you have to use a real plugin.

Answer (score -2):

Mocking in Golang is a bit tricky, and usually requires to generate some code. You need to write interfaces for the `plugin` package as well as for `plugin.Plugin` (if the package does not offer these by itself; something which alas is often the case). Then, use a mock generator (the usual suspect being [gomock](https://github.com/golang/mock)) to create mocks with all the usual mock functionality (expect, conditional return, etc.). In the production code, provide production implementations which you write yourself; they only consist of simple pass-through methods which call the real thing (`Open()` and `Lookup()` in this case). (Remember, you want to test whether `testCheckPluginFile` works correctly, not whether the `plugin` package works correctly.) By doing so, you should be able to follow proper TDD workflow.